# IUsing foreach function i need get the output?

Tags: php, foreach

```
<?php 
$val=array(4,10,15);
$val2=array('ravi,suresh,kumar'); 
foreach ($val2 as $title) { 
  foreach ($val as $title1) { 
    echo $title; 
    echo $title1; 
  }
}
?>
```

o/p:
ravi,suresh,kumar4ravi,suresh,kumar10ravi,suresh,kumar15

but i requeied
ravi 4
suresh10
kumar15

Comment: <?php
$val=array(4,10,15);
$val2=array('ravi,suresh,kumar');
  foreach ($val2 as $title) {
  foreach ($val as $title1) {
  echo $title;
   echo $title1;  }}?> //this is my code

Comment: What did you try? Where is the question? WHAT DO YOU WANT?

Comment: Dude, don't put ur code in the comment - put in in your question. Use the edit button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use one loop.

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($val); $i++) {
    print $val[$i] . " " . $val2[$i];
}
```

The issue with your nested for loops is that it iterates over the first element of val1, then all the elements of val 2. Then the 2nd element of val1, and all the elements of val2 and so on.

since you want to go through both at the same time, use a standard for loop.